# Personalize the Bootstrap theme?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal

I created a basket on bootstrap using "Font Awesome".

1) How to write the badge in red ?

2) How to put the badge on the cart ?

```
<a href="/cart">
<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-3x"></i>
<span class="badge">[quantity]</span>
<span>[commerce_order_total]</span>
</a>
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? What worked? What didn't? SO is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are You Looking for this

https://plnkr.co/edit/tL6GLun9iG5R9ifaaG74?p=preview

I just copy pasted a piece of code what I used already, Make Your trimming and adjust for your needs

HTML

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart fa-3x"></i>
    <span class="bs-badge badge-absolute float-right badge-red">87</span>
  </a>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
/* Styles go here */

a {
  outline: 0;
}

.btn {
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-weight: 400;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-image: none;
}


.fa {
  color: green;
}

.btn-lg {
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 0 16px;
  line-height: 44px;
  min-width: 56px;
  height: 46px;
}

.bs-badge.badge-absolute.float-right {
  right: -4px;
  left: auto;
}

.bs-badge.badge-absolute {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 5;
  top: -6px;
  left: -15px;
}

.bs-badge {
  font-size: 11px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 19px;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0 4px 0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.badge-red {
  background: red;
  border-color: #7a3ecc;
}


}
```

Comment: Updated Plunker https://plnkr.co/edit/XyrIOJAQnfcTPhhkki8V?p=preview

Comment: Thank you. But how to put it inside the shopping cart ?

Comment: did you mean, inside that icon @Mathieu

Comment: if you are planning to put inside that icon, it is not possible, you have to position it, in a way that it looks inside the icon

Comment: like this https://plnkr.co/edit/XyrIOJAQnfcTPhhkki8V?p=preview

Comment: @SibiRaj you're being overly technical, positioning it over the cart is still _"inside"_ of it.

Comment: haha ... @hungerstar